# Iframe not working for multiple rows

Tags: php

[image]I am trying to automate the hallticket process for an institution. This includes a certain verification process.

Iframe is working only for the first row, what should I do to open it  for multiple rows based on the row selection

**php code**

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows)) //Retriving the rows from the database
    {
    ?>
        <td><?php echo $app_id ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $first_name ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $last_name ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $email_id ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mobile_number ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $dd_number ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $course_name ?></td>
        <?php
        if($dd_submit==1 && $ht_sent==0)
        {?>
        <td class="verified"><span>Verified</span></td>
        <?php }elseif($dd_submit==0 && $ht_sent==0){ ?>
        <td class="non_verified"><span>None Verified</span></td>
        <?php }else{ ?> <td class="Pending"><span>Hall Ticket Sent</span></td>
        <?php } ?>
    <!-- I think the problem is here the java script is not repeating -->
        <td><button id="dialog" name="verify"  value="<?php echo $row['app_id'] ?>" > <img src="images/success_tick.png"></button><img src="images/meassage_table.png"><img src="images/comment.png"></td>  
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>

     <div id="dialogContent" title="DD Verification for Vinay Draksharam">
     <iframe src='ddverification_page.php?app_id=<?php echo $app_id ?> '></iframe> 



     Java Script 
    <script>
    $(function () {
       $("#dialogContent").dialog({
         autoOpen: false,
         modal: true
       });

       $('#dialog').click(function () {
         $("#dialogContent").dialog( "open" );
     });
    });
   </script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First problem- you have many rows but you only create one dialog. You probably have to put dialog creation inside loop to have separate dialog for each row. You also need some way to create connection between dialog and row. Best idea would probably to use $app_id as id of dialog.
What i would do:
PHP:

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rows)) //Retriving the rows from the database
    {
    ?>
        <td><?php echo $app_id ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $first_name ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $last_name ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $email_id ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $mobile_number ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $dd_number ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $course_name ?></td>
        <?php
        if($dd_submit==1 && $ht_sent==0)
        {?>
        <td class="verified"><span>Verified</span></td>
        <?php }elseif($dd_submit==0 && $ht_sent==0){ ?>
        <td class="non_verified"><span>None Verified</span></td>
        <?php }else{ ?> <td class="Pending"><span>Hall Ticket Sent</span></td>
        <?php } ?>
    <!-- I think the problem is here the java script is not repeating -->
        <td><button class="dialog" name="verify"  value="<?php echo $row['app_id'] ?>" >
<div class="dialogContent" id="dialogContent_<?php echo $app_id ?>" title="DD Verification for Vinay Draksharam">
     <iframe src='ddverification_page.php?app_id=<?php echo $app_id ?> '></iframe> </div>
<img src="images/success_tick.png"></button><img src="images/meassage_table.png"><img src="images/comment.png"></td>  
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
```

And Javascript:

```
$(function () {
       $(".dialogContent").dialog({
         autoOpen: false,
         modal: true
       });

       $('.dialog').click(function () {
         $("#dialogContent_"+$(this).val()).dialog( "open" );
     });
    });
```